# How can I access different repositories pointing to different collection using the same dao?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using two repositories pointing to two Mongo collection A and B. Both uses the same dao.

Example:

```
**First repository:**
@Repository
@Document(collection="A")
public interface Repository1 extends MongoRepository<Object1, String>
{   
    @Query("{'userActionInfo.createdBy' : ?0 }")
    List<Object> fetchAllByCreatedUser(String userId);
}

**Second repository:**
@Repository
@Document(collection="B")
public interface Repository2 extends MongoRepository<Object1, String>
{

    @Query("{'userActionInfo.createdBy' : ?0 }")
    List<Object> fetchAllByCreatedUser(String userId);
}

**DAO:**
public class Object implements Auditable,Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2802725098896112551L;
    @Id 
    private String Id;  
    private String Name;
}

**Service**
public Object save(Object obj) throws Exception {
if (obj.Id() > 1)
    {
        obj.setSomething("Yes");
        updated = Repository2.save(obj);
    }else{
        obj.setSomething("No");
        original = Repository1.save(obj);
}
return obj;
```

I have autowired both the repositories in service.I am using above Object to access/save data in the service but I am unable to save/access data in the respective collections.Any suggestions where am I going wrong here?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to save/access data"? You get some error?

Comment: This may or may not be an issue with your code, but PLEASE never create a new class named "Object" - it is almost guaranteed to cause confusion with Java's existing built-in class of that name.  For example, could your Repository's fetch methods be returning Java's "Object" rather than your Dao's "Object" ?

Comment: `@Document` on a repository doesn't do anything, so basically both repositories are the same. If you want this you will need multiple mongo template instances and wire it to the correct repository.

Comment: @racraman:  I just named it as Object for this example purpose only, the name of the actual class is different and not Object. Apologies for the confusion with the name.